# How to change iTunes metadata on PC?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, windows, metadata

I'm looking for a windows compatible program that will change iTunes metadata. I'm interested in changing tags that iTunes doesn't let me change, such as making a little HD flag appear next to the film and changing the media kind with all options.

All the programs are for Mac only, but the functionality I seek is something like Subler for PC.

Comment: Have you tried changing the info of the song/movie in iTunes by using `Ctrl` + `i` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something that will change metadata iTunes won't let me change.

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 1):

If they are ID3 tags, you can change them with exiftool (perl).

mutagen (Python) can also change them.